# Visual Studio Code: "The debugger is unable to evaluate this expression" error

Tags: c#, visual-studio, asp.net-core, visual-studio-code, .net-core

I have just started to use `VSCode` and while debugging the following backend code (`.NET Core`) I encounter *"The debugger is unable to evaluate this expression"* error. I add the following line to watch when the debugger hits on this line:

```
_context.Employees.Where(p => p.Name == search.Name)
```

Does VSCode not support such kind of debugging or watching as Visual Studio? Or do I make any mistake, need to apply any settings, etc.?

Comment: @Claies If you read what you suggest, you will see there is not any VSCode in that page.

Comment: I guess the term `search` is not available in the debugger context. What exactly do you want the debugger to do? Print a value or break on a condition?

Comment: Does visual studio code normally allow you to set watches on the results of LINQ expressions? It wouldn't surprise me if it didn't.. What are you watching, anyway? You don't assign the returned enumerable to anything

Comment: @CaiusJard Some variants work. I.e. `_context.Employees.Where(p => p.Name == "John Doe")` returns the employee instance for John Doe. Nice if the list is long.

Answer (score -1):

u need to use `FirstOrDefault(p => p.Name == search.Name)`  or
`ToList().FirstOrDefault(p => p.Name == search.Name)`.
u will always get that error if u are trying to call that data directly and this is what you are doing.